# Postgresql update column when passed condition

Tags: postgresql, case, conditional-statements

Is it possible, and if so, how can the following change be achieved?

Given the table:

```
param_tab
param_id serial
value integer
anothervalue integer
update_date TIMESTAMP
```

I would like to do something similar to this:

```
UPDATE param_tab pt
CASE WHEN CONDITION THEN pt.value = 14, pt.anothervalue = 20 END
pt.update_date = someTimestamp;
```

So `update_date` is always updated and `value` and `anothervalue` only in case of some condition

Answer (score 7):

Use the `CASE` statement in the correct place:

```
UPDATE param_tab pt
SET value = CASE WHEN condition THEN 14 ELSE pt.value END,
    anothervalue = CASE WHEN condition THEN 20 ELSE pt.anothervalue END,
    update_date = someTimestamp;
```

Comment: I modified little bit my question

Comment: Chasing the moving target.

Comment: Hi, thanks for Your answer. One more question. Lets say condition is (Select count(*) from ....) > 0 and in first case and second one that is same query. I think if I use same query in to different CASE statement then that statement query will be executed twice even if it is same query. It is possible for example in Postgres function to assign that result to another variable to be executed only once?

Comment: You are showing too little. It depends whether the condition depends on the row being updated or not. Maybe you should rewrite the query to use a join with a `FROM` clause.